# On upload verify picture really is a ID or passport document

Tags: javascript, php

I hope you can help me - I am pulling my hair out and cannot find a way to make this happen.

I want to add an upload on my website which involves a passport or ID photo, what I need to do is validate that it really is a passport or ID on upload.

There are a few websites and apps that do it so I know it's possible I would just like to know where I can look to get started - please can you help get me started or point me to an article to read?

Thanks all!

Comment: Most of the implementation that I know of are based on machine learning, check it out...

Comment: Your argument is understandable, but based on false premises. The amount of work that goes into such a feature makes it difficult for beginners to implement. Something being possible does not make it easy. That being said, good luck. You have a long road ahead of you, but you will master many useful things if you pursue it diligently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I had to do something similar for a project.

### I used Google's API: Google VISION to send me back the text on the ID card.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

### There is an equivalent at AWS if you want to make a comparison

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/amazon-rekognition-image-detection-and-recognition-powered-by-deep-learning/

There is an equivalent at AWS if you want to make a comparison.

Then with an algorithm of data cleaning and analysis with the coordinates in the image it is quite easy to know if you are dealing with a real document.

To find out if it is a real identity card or a real passport, you will also need to check with your country's authorities to see if the number matches.

It is a rather long job and requires patience.
If you don't have a big budget to take a turnkey tool, I advise you to develop everything yourself and not take time on wobbly projects on the Internet.

If you do not want to use an external service you can use this locally : https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/

(I had to add extra text to fix the broken link)

Comment: The question is off-topic since it's too broad. Answering off-topic question will just make people to keep asking them so try and avoid that. Also, answers that doesn't contain any actual solution in the answer itself (but rather just links off-site) is very much frowned upon here. Links change and if they do, your answer won't be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Even with this, you can't guarantee the document is legit AND you'd have to know in advance where everything was expected to be in every ID card / passport format you want to test for (and there are an awful lot of possibilities there). I don't think this is a bad suggestion though :).

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad.
He's just a beginner who needs to be redirected to research areas.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! Text detection via the API will do exactly what I need it to do, merely confirm this is a identity document, it's simply there to replace the old school manual scan.

Comment: Indeed if it is a project that must be used internationally yes it becomes very complicated.

My project was only to be used in France so it makes it much easier.

For the legality of the document, states often set up APIs on request to verify this type of information

Comment: Questions that can't easily be answered here (where the _solution_ is in the answer itself, not by linking outside of the site)  are too broad.

Comment: So for you it is impossible for someone who doesn't know where to start to ask for help?

Comment: On this specific site, it's too broad. Internet is huge though. There are other sites better suited for these kind of questions.

Comment: Ok I think it's a shame but it's good to know, thanks for the information.